# How to get 1st, 2nd, 3rd week format carbon laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, php-carbon

I need to get 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th week format from CarbonPeriod. What should i do to make it in text?

```
$carbonPeriod = CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, '1 week', $endDate);
            foreach ($carbonPeriod as $period) {
                $startPeriod = clone $period;
                $endPeriod = clone $period;
                $startRange = $parsedStartDate->gt($startPeriod->startOfWeek()) ? $startDate : $startPeriod->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
                $endRange = $parsedEndDate->lt($endPeriod->endOfWeek()) ? $endDate : $endPeriod->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
                $labels[] = $period->translatedFormat('F D Y'); //i need Jan 1st week 2021, Jan 2nd week 2021 and etc for the labels

            }
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? What do you need to get in `$labels` and what are you currently getting?

Comment: I need label for chart ["Jan 1st week 2021", "Jan 2nd week 2021", "Jan 3rd week 2021",  "Jan 4th week 2021",  "Feb 1st week 2021", "Feb 2nd week 2021" ] etc based on range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$carbonPeriod = CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, '1 week', $endDate);

foreach ($carbonPeriod as $index => $period) {
    $startPeriod = clone $period;
    $endPeriod = clone $period;
    $startRange = $parsedStartDate->gt($startPeriod->startOfWeek()) ? $startDate : $startPeriod->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
    $endRange = $parsedEndDate->lt($endPeriod->endOfWeek()) ? $endDate : $endPeriod->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
    $labels[] = $carbonPeriod->translate('ordinal', [':number' => $index + 1]);
}
```

Comment: It just return 'ordinal'

Comment: Tested Ok in https://try-carbon.herokuapp.com try to add `->locale('en')` before `->translate` you're maybe not in english.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the ordinal week within the given period. If that's indeed the case then you can do what you need using:

```
$locale = 'xxx'; //  Replace with your locale here
$nf = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
$carbonPeriod = CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, '1 week', $endDate);
foreach ($carbonPeriod as $i => $period) {
    $startPeriod = clone $period;
    $endPeriod = clone $period;
    $startRange = $parsedStartDate->gt($startPeriod->startOfWeek()) ? $startDate : $startPeriod->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
    $endRange = $parsedEndDate->lt($endPeriod->endOfWeek()) ? $endDate : $endPeriod->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
    $ordWeek = $nf->format($i);
    $labels[] = $period->translatedFormat('F')." $ordWeek". __("week")." ".$period->translatedFormat('Y'); // Should say "January 1st week 2021 
}
```

Note this requires the [intl extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
$CarbonPeriod = Carbon::now()->subDays(20);
    $today = Carbon::now();
    $weeks = intval(floor(($CarbonPeriod->diff($today)->days) / 7)) . 'st';
```

Result "2st"

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @Community why other user edit my answer ^_^

Comment: @KyleK your edit completely changed the answer and was not something the original author intended to answer with. Edits should only fix typos/fix formatting and clarify language based on what the author intended, not write your own answer.

Comment: @KyleK ok, I will remember it

Comment: OK @apokryfos written my own. The point was: with the foreach-loop, we actually don't need to calculate diff as we can use the `$index` (period as a week interval already), but if in an other context we need to calculate a number of weeks, then diffInWeeks is way more appropriate than diff()->days / 7 calculation, + intval() here is not needed.